# QGIS is closing when I try to load WIKIMaps/BING/GOOGLE maps loading with OpenLayers

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-openlayers-plugin, bing-maps, wikimapia

I am using QGIS 2.14 on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. 
My QGIS(2.14) is closing/quitting when I try to load Wikimaps/BING/GOOGLE maps loading with OpenLayers plugin.
How can I rectify this?

Comment: Try the QuickMapServices plugin instead.